# Black Jack with GUI, add objects to main frame from ActionListener in another class

Tags: java, swing, class, jframe, actionlistener

I made a Black Jack version with a gui. My problem is that to much of the implementation is in the same class that creates the window. The Class GameWindow both initilizes JFrame, adds visual objects like card icons, and text are stored to JLabels and then adds them to different JPanels.

Thats fine, but GameWindow (which implements ActionListener) also adds ActionListener to the buttons (which are simple JButtons not created classes), and implements the ActionPerformed.

I would like to create one class for each button, like "Class Deal implements ActionListener", and then let the class deal with the ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e). The problem is how can I add objects to GameWindow, from  this other class? 
And how do I send the Deck, Player(Score and Cards, stored in ArrayList) and Bank(Score and Cards), objects to the ActionPerformed in respective class (Deal, Stay and Hit)?

I didn´t want to post the code cause its alot and since I tried different solutions is a bit of a mess right now, but if you would want me to post any part of the code or all of it just tell me.

edit, thought it was to little text ;)

The classes I use right now, are 
CardDeck, has an ArrayList and methods like drawCard(), shuffle() etc.
Card, has an ImageIcon and an int that holds its value.
GameWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener, initilizes the JFrame, and also deal with the ActionPerformed associated with JButtons Deal, Hit and Stay (this is what I want to change).
Player, holds the player cards that are drawn in an ArrayList, and the score as an int
Bank, same as player but for the ai.
Main, executes GameWindow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide and conquer. You need a GameEngine class, which holds data and provides methods to manipulate it. You need a separate GameWindow which deals with displaying the game but relies on GameEngine to hold data and actually run the game. The ActionListners need a reference  to the GameEngine, and that's all; everything else they can do by calling methods on that.

The GameEngine itself may internally work with other classes: Deck, Card, etc. Try to make each class represent one well defined concept. Keep code near the data it uses.